# DB error when running Ballerina project for an older version

Tags: ballerina

I'm attempting to build a [Ballerina](http://ballerina.io) project which was written in an older(0.964.0) version of Ballerina. I used the below commands:

```
$ ~/Downloads/ballerina-tools-0.964.0/bin/ballerina build weekly_mail_notifier.bal
$ ~/Downloads/ballerina-tools-0.964.0/bin/ballerina run weekly_mail_notifier.balx
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error: error, message: error in sql connector configuration: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/github_issues?useSSL=false
        at ballerina.data.sql:ClientConnector.<init>(<native>)
        at org.wso2.contributions_from_outsiders:readPullRequestData(database_client.bal:93)
        at org.wso2.contributions_from_outsiders:generateMailBody(gmail_client.bal:70)
        at .:main(weekly_mail_notifier.bal:24)
```

Please note that I've already copied the MySQL JDBC drivers(mysql-connector-java-5.1.47) to  `~/Downloads/ballerina-tools-0.964.0/bre/lib` directory.

Comment: Got this fixed by using MySQL 5.7